# FS Calendar - number of dots

Tags: swift, xcode, calendar, fscalendar

The question is about popular calendar library: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

How can I set the correct number of dots, displaying the number of events for a given day in fs calendar?

Now if I try this simple code:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

    if self.datesWithFourEvents.contains(dateString) {
        return 4
    }

    if self.datesWithFiveEvents.contains(dateString) {
        return 7
    }

    return 0
}
```

The calendar will show maximum 3 dots per day.

How can this be fixed? If we need e.x. to show 4 or 7 dots - what should I change in code?

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of the library?

Comment: Hi! I have found an answer on Git, posted a detailed version here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question on Git about this: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/932

The solution is provided by the author of that thread.

So, in order to change maximum amount of dots from 3 to for example 5 - here is what you should do:

1. Find FSCalendarCell.m file in your project
2. In that file you need to find two blocks of code:

2.1 First one you can discover by in search bar looking for:

```
self.eventLayers = [NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray];
```

After that line there are the brackets - change text in them to:

```
(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

2.2 Than search for text:

```
_numberOfEvents = MIN(MAX(numberOfEvents,0),3)
```

And replace 3 to 5.

And here you are! Now you can see 5 dots instead of 3. You can change the number to whatever you want - just instead of 5 put a number you like.